# Android SharedPreferences Get all strings with same key?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Im fairly new to android and java programming and I need help getting all the data with the same key so I can display it in a list view. (At the moment it gets all values no matter what the key is)

Here is my code to add the data to SharedPreferences:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub              
String checkListStringData = etItemName.getText().toString();
checkListData = getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
SharedPreferences.Editor checkListEditor = checkListData.edit();
checkListEditor.putString(checkListStringData + "ItemName",checkListStringData);
checkListEditor.commit();

String checkListDataReturned = checkListData.getString(currentList + "ItemName", "");
tvTitle.setText(checkListDataReturned);

updateListView();
etItemName.setText("");
};
});
}
```

And here is my code to Load the SharedPreferences:

```
private void updateListView() {
    final ListView lvCheckList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCheckList);
    Map<String,?> keys = checkListData.getAll();

    ArrayList<String> checkListStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
        if (entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
            checkListStrings.add((String) entry.getValue());
        }

    ArrayAdapter<String> checkListArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, checkListStrings );

    lvCheckList.setAdapter(checkListArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: "getting all the data with the same key" -- there is only one value per key.

Comment: If you look at the code you will see that when data is saved it is saved with a variable as the key.

Comment: When you save data with the same key, previous data will be overwritten

Comment: Actually look at the code and you'll know what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

SharedPreferences are a key/value data store.  That means each key holds exactly one value.  You cannot have multiple values for one key.  You also cannot have the same key in the preference multiple times, reusing the same key will cause the old value to be overwritten.

What you're doing above is actually creating new keys for each item.  That will work, although its odd and redundant to have the key and its value be basically identical like that.  The problem is that since you don't have a predefined key (its generated) the only way to find all the keys is to walk the preference like you're doing.  Its really not how shared preferences were meant to be used and is not recommended. You should probably be using a different datastore.  What you should be using depends on what these are used for, but the answer is likely a database.

Answer (score 2):

There can be only 1 (one) string value for a any particular key in preferences.

If you will save the key-value for multiple times - it will be overwritten with the last value.

If you will read the key-value for multiple times - it will return the same value many times.

If you need to save multiple values -

- use the SQLite database
- combine values into JSON array, and save it in prefs

See the docs for details.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I have a way around it.

String checkListStringData = etItemName.getText().toString();
checkListData = getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
String checkListStringData = etItemName.getText().toString();
checkListData = getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
SharedPreferences.Editor checkListEditor = checkListData.edit();

Comment: Your code seems to be invalid - `checkListStringData` definition is duplicated, as I can see your badly-formatted code.